# How do I move coordinates [x,y] from a 2D array to the right? c#

Tags: c#

Hello so recently I have been given an assignment to create a small game, but see I have ran into a problem. When I try to move my Player who starts out at a set position he will shift to the right once but it seems he is still locked at the starting spot and upon entering the number to shift him right again, the same answer(coordinates I have printed out) are the same and game board is also the same. https://gyazo.com/9f23419a3300232d3f3d9e1168202cf3

```
    public string player(int movement)
    {
        int playerX = map.GetLength(0)-3; //rows
        int playerY = map.GetLength(1)-25; //columns

        if (movement == 8)
        {
            playerX--;
            map[playerX, playerY] = "P";
            Console.WriteLine("The player is located at: " + playerX +","+ playerY);
        }
        else if (movement == 6)
        {
            playerY++;
            map[playerX, playerY] = "P";
            Console.WriteLine("The player is located at: " + playerX + "," + playerY);
        }
        else if (movement == 2)
        {
            playerX++;
            map[playerX, playerY] = "P";
            Console.WriteLine("The player is located at: " + playerX + "," + playerY);
        }
        else if (movement == 4)
        {
            playerY--;
            map[playerX, playerY] = "P";
            Console.WriteLine("The player is located at: " + playerX + "," + playerY);
        }  
        else
        {
            map[playerX,playerY] = "P";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the `player` method, the position is the same because you are using local variables to store the position.

What I assume you want is to use a global variable, and set the position when the game starts.

Move the variable declarations outside of your method: (Put these inside the class but not inside the method)

```
int playerX, playerY;
```

Set the position when the map is created.

```
map = // Something
playerX = map.GetLength(0)-3; //rows
playerY = map.GetLength(1)-25; //columns
```

Comment: Yeah I got the answer from a class mate shortly after, kind of a dumb mistake haha. Thanks though. :D